# How to connect to local Docker on Windows with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, docker

How to connect to local Docker on Windows with Eclipse?

I installed latest docker using DOCKER TOOLBOX on Windows 10 (Home)

```
$ docker info
...
Server Version: 1.12.1
```

I got latest Eclipse Neon 4.5 and installed

Docker Tooling    2.0.0.201606101757  org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.feature.feature.group Eclipse Linux Tools

I switch to Docker perspective.
How to connect to local docker?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, there is <kbd>Search</kbd> button.

But the first time it gave me `default` with wrong URL,
should be `https://192.168.99.100:2376` (as on Windows)

Some intro to Eclipse Docker tooling is at https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2015/june/article3.php